# Power Query: Find Percentile Within Group

Tags: powerquery, m

I have multiple data sources coming together and am creating a heatmap highlighting each. My data is set up in the following way:

```
Name | Category | Score
```

I'd like to create a fourth column that shows the percentile of the score **within each category** as each category has it's own scale (some are 0-5, some are 0-100, etc.)

Is this using GroupBy?

Comment: Just need further clarification. Do you have the need to do so within Power Query (M)? If your data is already unique (Combination Name + Category appears only once with a score) it is easier and more performant to achieve that through a measure (DAX). Depending on your answer I can give you some advice!

Comment: If I did this as a measure in DAX, how would I use this as my formatting? I used PERCENTILE to do this but it did not group the scores like I intended